# oldvalues of SqlDatasource for dynamic gridview-templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

For a dynamic Gridview i am generating columns at runtime like this:

```
TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
tf.HeaderText = colName;
tf.ItemTemplate = new GenericItem(ListItemType.Item, colName, "Command");
tf.EditItemTemplate = new GenericItem(ListItemType.EditItem, 
Gridview1.Columns.Add(tf);
```

The GenericItem implements IBindableTemplate:

```
public class GenericItem : IBindableTemplate
```

This works fine, but when i am trying to update some columns, i need to have access to the old values. I assumed i could just use this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dsGridview" OldValuesParameterFormatString="old_{0}" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" />
```

But when i want to access the oldvalues property of my datasource in the RowUpdating event of the Gridview i noticed that the oldvalues collection is empty (the newvalues collection is filled just fine)

Does anybody know how i can get those oldvalues?

Best regards,
r3try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is not how i wanted to solve it - but as there are no other suggestions here is how i worked around my problem. Maybe someone else has the same problem:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //GET THE OLD VALUES
        myOldValues.Clear();
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gv.DataBind();

        //populate 
        for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataControlFieldCell cell = gv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;
            gv.Columns[i].ExtractValuesFromCell(myOldValues, cell, DataControlRowState.Edit, true);
        }

        Session["MyOldValues"] = myOldValues;

    }
```